# Missing .pom files for the jar artifacts after upgrading jfrog artifact from 3.4.1 to 4.7

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory, artifacts

I use JFrog Artifactory for managing dependencies. We recently upgraded from 3.4.1 to 4.7 and took a backup of everything before doing an upgrade.

My issue is: All `.pom` files are missing now. I see only `.jar` files in the Artifactory, but the associated `.pom` files are missing. Is there a way I can get these POMs or auto-generate them? I know that manually deploying artifacts will generate new POMs, but we have thousands of artifacts.

Comment: Did you install a new instance of Artifactory 4.7 and imported the backup? did you see any errors while importing/upgrading?

Comment: no there were no errors while upgarding . I imported configs  from old instance , and pointed to the old filestore location

Comment: can you describe (in the question) the exact procedure you applied for the upgrade? loosing all the .pom file is a highly irregular situation

Comment: we were on jfrog 3.4.1 version
1. yum upgrade to 3.9.5 
2.

Comment: we were on jfrog 3.4.1 version
1.took backup of the older instance ( copied whole instance into a safe location)
2.Took system export (Exculde content) and repository export as well ( as plan-b ) 
We wanted to upgrade to 4.7 version( as it supports bower integration)

1. yum upgrade to 3.9.5 (nearest upgrade to 3.4.1)
2.Then yum install to 4.7 version
3.modified storage.properties , pointed FileStoredir to older instance filestore dir
4.We have sql server database tied to the artifactory , so copied jdbcsql.jar to the new artifactory instance tomcat location
5.sevice artifactory start